# Show that the solution to PDE converges to the initial condition in $L^2$

Tags: sequences-and-series, partial-differential-equations, fourier-series, uniform-convergence, heat-equation

I have a solution, $u(x,t)$, to the heat equation $u_t-u_{xx} = 0$ with initial condition $u(x,0) = f(x)$.

I would like to show that as $t \rightarrow 0$, the solution $u(x,t)$ tends to the initial condition $f(x)$. In other words

$$
\lim_{t \rightarrow 0} \int|u(x,t) - f(x)|^2 = 0
$$

My solution $u(x,t)$ is an infinite series. I think I need to use the M-test to show that $u(x,t)$ converges uniformly to $f(x)$, but i'm not sure where the fact that this convergence is in $L^2$ comes to play.

Thanks

Comment: It would definitely be helpful to see what the domain is and what your series solution is. The $M$-test is typically used to prove convergence of a series without needing to identify what it converges to. Here you can likely prove uniform convergence using explicit bounds.

Comment: @User8128 is there not an approach that works in general. As in, how would one usually show that a series converges to some function in $L^2$?

Comment: If you have no information about the functions $u(\cdot,t)$ then there is no general way to prove that they converge to $f$ in $L^2$ as $t\to0$. If want to prove $u(\cdot,t) \to f$ in $L^2$ you need to use something specific about the functions $u(\cdot,t)$.   Here it seems you have $u(\cdot,t) = \sum^\infty_{n=1} g_n(\cdot,t)$. You could likely prove that for fixed $t$, the series converges uniformly using the $M$-test. But to prove it converges to $f$ in $L^2$ as $t\to0$, you need to bound $\|u(\cdot,t)-f\|_{L^2}$. To do that you will need to use something specific about $u(\cdot,t)$.